# check if last row or not when running loops in PHP

Tags: php

I am using this PHP Code to run queries to a MySQL Database:

```
$i=0;
$display='[';
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from tickets where status = :status and deleted = :deleted ");
$stmt->execute(array(':status' => 'Open', ':deleted' => ''));
$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$counter = count($records);
foreach($records as $result) {
    $i++;
    $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from contacts where sequence = :sequence ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':sequence' => $result["contact"]));
    $contact = $stmt->fetch();

    $display.='{';
    $display.='"customer":"'.$contact["forename"].' '.$contact["surname"].'",';
    $display.='"subject":"'.$result["subject"].'"';
    if($counter == $i) {
        $display.='},';
    } else {
        $display.='}';
    }
}
$display.=']';
```

I would ideally like the end result to show as the below:

```
[{"customer":"Carol","subject":"Fax not working"}{"customer":"Clive","subject":"VoIP Issues"}{"customer":"Leigh ","subject":"company Antaeus"}{"customer":"Debbie","subject":"emails"}{"customer":"Kim","subject":"Printer setup"}{"customer":"Sue ","subject":"Phone"}{"customer":"Sandra","subject":"Debbie's computer "}{"customer":"Daniel","subject":"Email Attachments"}{"customer":"Lara","subject":"Internet Issues"}]
```

However, at the moment it looks like:

```
[{"customer":"Carol","subject":"Fax not working"}{"customer":"Clive","subject":"VoIP Issues"}{"customer":"Leigh ","subject":"company Antaeus"}{"customer":"Debbie","subject":"emails"}{"customer":"Kim","subject":"Printer setup"}{"customer":"Sue ","subject":"Phone"}{"customer":"Sandra","subject":"Debbie's computer "}{"customer":"Daniel","subject":"Email Attachments"}{"customer":"Lara","subject":"Internet Issues"},]
```

Notice the comma on the end before the `]`

How can i make sure that comma does not show at the end, I tried using the if statement in my loop with the counters (`$counter` and `$i`) but that didn't work

Comment: Woah wait a minute. Are you trying to build a JSON string? Don't do that yourself, use `json_encode()` instead.  Collect everything into a single array then `json_encode($the_array)`

Comment: yeah i am, I'm very new to this. do you have any example you can show me ?

Comment: And look into mysql `JOIN`'s to only run one sql statement instead of loads of sql statements in your loop.

Comment: By the way, in general when you need to build a list separated by a character, you should either use the counter you already have (add a comma at the start if the counter is bigger than 0) or build an array and use `implode` to generate a string. Not that you should do that here, but just in case...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without any loops and a single inner join.  Instead of manually constructing a JSON string, you are advised to use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to do it for you.  Run a single join query, and collect the rows into a single array which is encoded as JSON..

This eliminates the need for all your other machinery - loops, and counters.

```
// A single join query will return everything you need from both tables.
// Customer names can be concatenated here into a single Customer field
// You only appear to need tickets.subject.
// And reading your queries, the table relation appears to be tickets.contact = contacts.sequence
$sql = '
SELECT
  t.subject AS Subject,
  CONCAT(c.forename, ' ', c.surname) AS Customer
FROM 
  tickets t 
  INNER JOIN contacts c ON t.contact = c.sequence
WHERE status = :status AND deleted = :deleted;
';
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
if ($stmt) {
  $stmt->execute(array(':status' => 'Open', ':deleted' => ''));
  // Fetch all rows...
  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

  // Now $rows looks like the 2D array needed, you can directly JSON encode it
  $output = json_encode($rows);
}

// Inspect it...
echo $output;
```

I'll point out that although you are absolutely right to be in the habit of bound parameters, there actually isn't a need for them here since the strings `'Open'` and `''` are static and known. You can just call a plain `query()` on this instead of `prepare()/execute()`.

```
// No user input, static strings only, means no need for params
$sql = "
SELECT
  t.subject AS Subject,
  CONCAT(c.forename, ' ', c.surname) AS Customer
FROM 
  tickets t 
  INNER JOIN contacts c ON t.contact = c.sequence
WHERE status = 'Open' AND deleted = '';
";
// Just a simple query() call
$result = $pdo_conn->query($sql);
if ($result) {
  $rows = $result->fetchAll();
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation of only binding where actually necessary.